# DataBinding: 'DatePickerControl.DatePicker' does not contain a property with the name 'Text'

Tags: c#

I tried using date/time, time, but it doesn't help.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'DatePickerControl.DatePicker' does not contain a property with the name 'Text'.

```
Source Error: 


Line 31:         DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserId", UserGUID.ToString());
Line 32: 
Line 33:         DataSource.Insert();//here is the error
Line 34:         
Line 35:     }
```

Here is the html code :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="InsertExtraInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASPNETDBConnectionString1 %>"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [UserDetails] ([UserId], [CustName], [CustNum], [CustRole], [CustStatus], [PName], [PEmail], [PRole], [WedDate]) VALUES (@UserId, @CustName, @CustNum, @CustRole, @CustStatus, @PName, @PEmail, @PRole, @WedDate)"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASPNETDBConnectionString1.ProviderName %>">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustName" Type="String" ControlID="CustName" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustNum" Type="String" ControlID="CustNum" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustRole" Type="String" ControlID="CustRole" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustStatus" Type="String" ControlID="CustStatus" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="PName" Type="String" ControlID="PName" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="PEmail" Type="String" ControlID="PEmail" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="PRole" Type="String" ControlID="PRole" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="WedDate" Type="String" ControlID="WedDate" PropertyName="Text"/>
    </InsertParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `PropertyName="SelectedValue"` and `Type="DateTime"`

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="WedDate" Type="DateTime" ControlID="WedDate" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
```

### EDIT:

try

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="WedDate" Type="DateTime" ControlID="WedDate" PropertyName="SelectedDate"/>
```

Comment: 'DatePickerControl.DatePicker' does not contain a property with the name 'SelectedValue'.
this errors appear after i adding in selectedvalue to its propertyname.

Comment: Nope, this is not jquary datepicker. 

this is the code i added into my html: 
    
<cc1:DatePicker ID="WedDate" runat="server" CalendarDate="" 
                                    TextCssClass="" /> </code>

Comment: @user1467175 try with "SelectedDate"

Comment: I tried. but they come out this error: 
DataBinding: 'DatePickerControl.DatePicker' does not contain a property with the name 'SelectedDate'.

Comment: @user1467175 what is this date picker? is this 3rd party tool?

Comment: I downloaded it on the internet, and add it into the toolbox of Microsoft Visual studio.

Comment: from where you download it? there should be a documentation for that. you can find the property need to be called from that.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`Type="String"` to `Type="DateTime"`  and
`PropertyName="Text"` to `PropertyName="SelectedDate"`
on this line

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="WedDate" Type="DateTime" ControlID="WedDate" PropertyName="SelectedDate" />
```

Comment: I tried. but they come out this error: 
DataBinding: 'DatePickerControl.DatePicker' does not contain a property with the name 'SelectedDate'.